# Infinite scroll on a page with no scroll bars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my infinite scroll method:

```
$(window).on('scroll', this.infiniteScroll);

p.infiniteScroll = function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        //get data
    }
};
```

My page initially fills with content and when the user scrolls to the bottom I load more data and output.

When the user is viewing the site through a large screen or large browser window, the initial content does not fill the page so the user cannot scroll and therefore the scroll function is never called.

What would be the best way to fix this? So when there is not enough content to make scroll bars appear, the user tries to scroll, more results should appear.

Comment: Quick solution would be to - Use css media queries to increase the size of the content when displaying on larger screens?

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

Comment: Good idea, was looking for something more than a 'hack' though. Thanks anyway.

Comment: width and height 100%? css overflow hidden? got any sample code for rest?

Comment: If there are more results to load wouldn't it be better just to load them if you detect there is not enough content for a scroll bar to appear. Or increase the number of items shown at one time to ensure a scroll bar appears.